# Different definitions of p-fusion and Mislin's theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, finite-groups, group-cohomology, homology

Currently, I am trying to understand and compute homology of finite groups with coefficients in a field of positive characteristic. So, I was searching for some results that could reduce this problem (for example, to p-groups).

The first result I found was in D. J. Benson's book "Representations and Cohomology I":

**Theorem (Prop. 3.8.4):** If $H$ controls $p$-fusion in $G$ and the $p'$ part of $|G|$ is invertible in $R$ (a commutative ring), then the restriction map gives a isomorphism $H^n(G,R)\cong H^n(H,R)$.

I also found a theorem of Mislin, which is stated [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.75.3215&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (Alperin, On a theorem of Mislin, 2006) in this way:

**Mislin's theorem:** Given a field k of characteristic $p>0$, we have that the restriction map gives an isomorphism $H^n(G,k)\cong H^n(H,k)$ if, and only if, $H$ is weakly $p$-embedded in $G$.

So, these seem to be great results and I sought to understand the conditions of fusion and $p$-embedded, which are the following:

**Definition 1** (in D. J. Benson's book I): **$H$ controls $p$-fusion in $G$** if $H$ contains a $p$-Sylow and, for every $p$-subgroup $K$ of $H$ such that $gKg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $H$ (for some $g\in G$), there exists $h\in H$ such that $h^{-1}g\in C_G(K)$ (i.e. $gkg^{-1}=hkh^{-1}$ for every $k\in K$).

However, a concept more frequently found in the literature is the following:

**Definition 2**: Given groups $S ≤ H ≤ G$ ($S$ a $p$-Sylow), $H$ is said to **control fusion of $S$ in $G$** if every pair of elements of $S$ that are conjugated by some element $g\in G$ are also conjugated by some $h\in H$.
(That is, definition 1 with $K$ substituted by elements $s\in S$.)

Also, we have the condition of Mislin's theorem above:

**Definition 3:** $H$ is **weakly $p$-embedded** in $G$ if whenever $Q$ is a $p$-subgroup of H then $N_G(Q)/C_G(Q)$ is isomorphic with $N_H(Q)/C_H(Q)$.

Finally, my questions are:

**1)** Are any of these definitions equivalent?

**2)** The theorem of Benson's book (even if $R=k$) is also valid if we use definition 2? (Of course, an affirmative answer to the first question can answer this.)

**3)** Are these kind of results also valid for homology?

Comment: When $H$ itself is a Sylow $p$-subgroup, the three definitions agree.